# Will_paginate and rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Has anyone come across this error?

```
protected method `wp_parse_options' called for #<Class:0x0000010258d510>

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:15:in `show'
```

Products Controller - line 15

```
@productresources = @product.resources.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

Controller: `Products`

Action: `Show`

It works perfectly in the `Index` action.

Full Stack Trace:

```
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:14:in `block in wp_parse_options'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/relation.rb:240:in `block in scoping'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/scoping.rb:98:in `with_scope'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/relation.rb:240:in `scoping'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:14:in `wp_parse_options'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:101:in `method_missing'
will_paginate (3.0.pre4) lib/will_paginate/finders/active_record.rb:109:in `paginate'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:18:in `show'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__2335962783478714721__process_action__1985377926501664410__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2418333975921747071__call__3765725717641636098__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/dol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/dol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/dol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

@Ryan Bigg - here's the stack trace. I'm not sure what happened, but I'm pretty sure its Will_paginate.

@mohamed.magdy - As far as I understand, Will_paginate broke when 3.1 was released but then was fixed later. I have got the new will_paginate version to work in 3.1, but it doesn't work in this show action for some reason.

Comment: Please show us the full stacktrace associated with that error.

Comment: Isn't will_paginate died after Rails 3.1? Here's my source http://gitinit.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/will_paginate-is-broken-in-rails-3-1/

Comment: I have it working in a 3.2.1 app with no problems, so it is possible. I'm using v 3.0.3 of the gem.

Comment: @mohamed.magdy In fact, a few months after I wrote that post, will_paginate started updating again and should be compatible with current versions of Rails now. I should probably update my post to reflect that!